# How to create custom dialect and add it to application.yml file in Grails 3?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I am creating a REST API using **Grails 3** and Spring Security Rest plugin.
I am using **MySQL** as my back end.
But I always get a 401 error whenever I try to send a request to the /api/login endpoint.
Hence, I am assuming that boolean properties of my Domain class are not being mapped properly in the MySQL database. Hence, Spring Security is throwing 401 error.
In short, I want to create the following **custom dialect**

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapp

import java.sql.Types
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

class MyDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
   public MyDialect() {
      registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "boolean")
   }
}
```

But I am confused as to how to do it. Should I create a new java file or a Groovy file? Also in which directory within my grails app directory should I create my custom dialect?

Also I need to know what changes should I make in my **application.yml** file so as to use my custom dialect.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
package my.package

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

class ImprovedMySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    @Override
    public String getDropSequenceString(String sequenceName) {
        // Adding the "if exists" clause to avoid warnings
        return "drop sequence if exists " + sequenceName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        // We don't need to drop constraints before dropping tables, that just leads to error
        // messages about missing tables when we don't have a schema in the database
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in your application.yml

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        #logSql: true
        #formatSql: true
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        #dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        dialect: my.package.ImprovedMySQLDialect
```

Typically you will place your improvedDialect file inside `src/main/groovy/my/package/ImprovedMySQLDialect.groovy`  in grails 2 it is a similar path the `src/main` is `src/groovy`

You place domain classes or objects that become your database model inside -> grails-app/domain

All your helper classes goes inside src/main (java groovy)

You mean garbage with 0101 inside those boxes? I don't think it is going to give you X/Y or A tick box or a numeric value of 0/1 it will give you that as `Boolean`

Alternatively declare your Boolean as a `Byte` or `byte`

```
byte privacy 
boolean main=false

  static mapping = {
        cache true
        privacy(sqlType: 'tinyint(2)')
        main(sqlType: 'bit(1)'
  }
```

Is some alternatives to what you are trying to do ...

Bytes or Booleans in effect can be 3 states null or false or true and you can treat it in those 3 ways boolean declaration is on or off.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Can you also help me out with where to create the file?In which directory within my app directory?

Comment: Still not working. I want boolean in Grails to be mapped as TINYINT in MySQL. But after running the above script and viewing in MySQL command line it still shows as garbage under the boolean column.

Comment: The thing is I don't mind declaring my property as byte or bit. But the problem is that those scripts are generated by a Spring Security plugin. If during the API call the system cannot read the enabled column value properly then the problem may persist.

Comment: well if you are concerned about the types  I would suggest following the above example of boolean main where the sqlType was set to bit(1) I think this is what you are trying to achieve - then you would have to test it through the rest call. Although I think u need to think about enabling sql logging as well as spring security logging to see what on earth is going on and why it is failing.. Its easy to assume something and run around for hours over the wrong thing I am no expert in the rest side of spring security just giving u my opinion around all of this